# Youtube uploading Video Android

Tags: android, video, upload, youtube

I'm trying to upload a video to YouTube in Android.
I want the user to validate with his Google Account using GoogleAuthUtil and it works. Then I have user name and token and the uriFile loaded too.

The final step I want to do is upload it to Youtube. To do this I followed this code https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/source/browse/trunk/?r=38

My problem in my code is in this part:

```
File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
long mFileSize = file.length();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
credential.setAccessToken(mToken);

HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

YouTube youtube =
        new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
                "fanscup").build();

InputStream fileInputStream = null;
try {
    mFileSize = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "r").getStatSize();
    fileInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(getApplicationContext().toString(), e.getMessage());
}
ResumableUpload.upload(youtube, fileInputStream, mFileSize, getApplicationContext());
```

And when I try to upload the video I got this error:

> Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
>
> java.io.IOException: Permission denied
>
> resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.util.Clock
>
> at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential. (Credential.java:200)
>
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.(GoogleCredential.java:187)
>
> at com.library_fanscup.UploadActivity$1.onPostExecute(UploadActivity.java:483)
>
> at com.library_fanscup.UploadActivity$1.onPostExecute(UploadActivity.java:1)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
>
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
>
> exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)

Can anybody help me? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use below class

public static void uploadVideo(String msg, final Context context){
        //List scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");

```
    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
    GoogleCredential googleCredential =
            new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(transport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setClientSecrets("client_id", "client_scretekey").build();
    googleCredential.setAccessToken("Access_token");
    googleCredential.setRefreshToken("refresh_token");

    String appName ="";
    final YouTube youtube =
            new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, googleCredential).setApplicationName(
                    appName).build();

    InputStream fileInputStream = null;
    long fileSize = 0;
    File filem=new File(msg);
    Uri mFileUri=Uri.fromFile(filem);
    try {
        fileSize = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(mFileUri, "r").getStatSize();
        fileInputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mFileUri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final NotificationManager notifyManager =
            (NotificationManager)context. getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle("Uploading Video")
            .setContentText("Live Streaming")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();

    String videoId = null;
    try {
        // Add extra information to the video before uploading.
        Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();
        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
        status.setPrivacyStatus("public");

        videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

        // We set a majority of the metadata with the VideoSnippet object.
        VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        snippet.setTitle("Live Streaming Upload On " + cal.getTime());
        snippet.setDescription("Live Streaming Upload video on youtube "
                + "on " + cal.getTime());
        // Set your keywords.
        snippet.setTags(Arrays.asList("Android client 1",
                Upload.generateKeywordFromPlaylistId("client_id")));
        // Set completed snippet to the video object.
        videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);
        InputStreamContent mediaContent =
                new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT, new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
        mediaContent.setLength(fileSize);
        YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert =
                youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata,
                        mediaContent);


                // Set the upload type and add event listener.
                MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

                uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

                final long FileSize = fileSize;
                MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
                    public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                        switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                            case INITIATION_STARTED:
                                builder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.initiation_started)).setProgress((int) FileSize,
                                        (int) uploader.getNumBytesUploaded(), false);

                                notifyManager.notify((int)uniqueId, builder.build());
                                break;
                            case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                                builder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.initiation_completed)).setProgress((int) FileSize,
                                        (int) uploader.getNumBytesUploaded(), false);
                                notifyManager.notify((int)uniqueId, builder.build());
                                break;
                            case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                                builder
                                        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.youtube_upload) +
                                                (int) (uploader.getProgress() * 100) + "%")
                                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.upload_in_progress))
                                        .setProgress((int) FileSize, (int) uploader.getNumBytesUploaded(), false);
                                notifyManager.notify((int)uniqueId, builder.build());
                                break;
                            case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                                builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.yt_upload_completed))
                                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.upload_completed))
                                        // Removes the progress bar
                                        .setProgress(0, 0, false);
                                notifyManager.notify((int)uniqueId, builder.build());

                            case NOT_STARTED:
                                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),context.getString(R.string.upload_not_started));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };
                uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

        // Execute upload.
        Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
        Log.d(TAG, "Video upload completed");

        videoId = returnedVideo.getId();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("videoId = [%s]", videoId));
        //delete video after video upload completed

    } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException", availabilityException);
        notifyFailedUpload(context, context.getString(R.string.cant_access_play), notifyManager, builder);
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("UserRecoverableAuthIOException: %s",
                userRecoverableException.getMessage()));
        requestAuth(context, userRecoverableException);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
        notifyFailedUpload(context,context.getString(R.string.please_try_again), notifyManager, builder);
    }

}
```